# Dependency Injection with child objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a class called `User` and it has a property of `List <Role>`.

Using dependency injection how do I populate the Roles given that I need to know the user first? I.e. the roles are dependent on the user so I can't inject them on instantiation as I do not know the user at this point as I need to first call a method like `GetUser (username);` which returns a user object.

### Update

This is the class structure I have

```
public partial class User:IUser
{
    private List<IUserRole> _userRoles = new List<IUserRole>();

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User GetUserByID(int id, dbEntities context)
    {
        User user = new User();
        using(context)
        {
            user = (from u in context.Users where u.ID == id select u).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return user;
    }

    public User GetUser(string username, string password, dbEntities context)
    {
        User user = new User();
        using (context)
        {
            user = (from u in context.Users where u.Username==username && u.Password==password select u).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return user;
    }

    List<IUserRole> UserRoles 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _userRoles;
        }
        set
        {
            _userRoles = value;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, a populated user object is retrieved via various methods. However I really want the UserRoles to be returned with the object too but injecting the roles would not work as they can not be retrieved until the user is populated.

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your classes so we have a better understanding of their layout?

Comment: How are you injecting the User currently? I'd suggest wherever the User is resolved it makes the most sense to populate roles also.

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Having directly accessible `List<Roles>` forces you populate the list at the moment `User` is created. It means your "factory" for the `User` object need to also call "role provider" to obtain list of roles for the user.

Assuming you are using some DI container like Unity code would look similar to:

```
_container.RegisterFactory(container => 
 {
     var user = new User(); 
     user.Roles = container.Resolve<IRolesProvider>()
            .GetRolesForUser(user);
     return user;
 });
```

Alternatively you can add dependency to "roles provider" to `User` and compute (possibly with caching) on demand:

```
 class User
 {
    IRolesProvider roles;
    public User(IRolesProvider roles,....)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
        ...
    }

    public List<Roles> { get { return roles.GetRolesForUser(this);}}
    ...
 }
```

Comment: The first suggestion makes sense to me, however is this then strictly dependency injection as I would be simply setting the property?

Comment: @coolblue2000 first  is not dependency injection as there is no real dependency - User acts more like plain object in this case. It is up to you to decide whether `User` *depends* on "roles provider" (second sample) or simply *knows* set of its own "roles" (first sample) .

Comment: On second thoughts, I do not populate the user object on instantiation.  I call a method to populate it so the above solution would not work.

Comment: @coolblue2000 I see - since your "User" mixes responsibilities (being "user" and reading/writing to different storage mediums as shown) it is harder to extract dependencies. Frequently persistence and functionality are split into separate types.

Comment: Ah ok. I will look into separating the functionality then. Thank you.